# How to I find and kill remotely a process running on CentOS-5.x?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

- **Context:** Ran a backup thinking it'd take no more than 1-hour... and it's still going. The process is a MySQL DB backup that has the DB tables locked.
- **OS:** CentOS-5.x
- **Goal:** Find and kill remotely a process running on CentOS-5.x

**Possible Requested Help:**

**(1)** How do I find it, meaning how do I view all process and sort by CPU use; since I have no idea what the process is, but I'm guessing it's taking up most the CPU cycles now and has a name I'll figure out.

**(2)** How do I kill it. Please use the following notation, where # is the CMD-line itself: `# cd /` -- meaning change directory to root. If the command allows sudo to be used, include it if if it's unlikely to be needed, example: `# sudo cd /secure` -- meaning change directory to `/secure` based on sudo rights.

**NOTE:** Really not sure if the above is clear, so if you have any questions, please comment and I'll reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top` will show you the processes on the system, sorted in default by CPU usage. Press `k` to select a process to kill. Press `q` when you want to exit top.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: +1 Thanks, I'll try it right now.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Entered the PID, hit ENTER, and got this: "Kill PID 2 with signal [15]:" -- did a quick google search and it appears I enter the number "9" -- is that correct, and if so, what does that mean? For now, I exited top, and then ran it again to confirm the PID is still running; which it is.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: So, figure out that it was requesting to run "signal 15" and was requesting I enter (y/n) -- hit "y" -- and got this: " Kill of PID '2' with '15' failed: Operation not permitted" -- do I need to run top as sudo, or login as root? Thanks!

Comment: 9 is `SIGKILL`, which is a bit harsh since it doesn't let the program do any cleanup. Give it 15 (`SIGTERM`) then wait a bit. If it still refuses to die, then you can try `SIGKILL`.

Comment: If you want to kill arbitrary processes then you will need to run `top` as root, whether you use `sudo` or log in as root directly.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: typed "sudo top"; then k; then entered PID;  then typed y -- I did not get the "Operation not permitted" response, but the PID's still there and it's already been 6 minutes, how long should I give it -- and if it's still running what do I do, and how bad is SIG-9; meaning the process is a MySQL DB backup that has the DB tables locked...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: If a CMD like "top" requires "sudo top" -- please include it in your answer. Thank you, just +1 all your replies.

Comment: Having locked the tables is bad; you'll probably have to restart MySQL after killing it. Also, top itself doesn't require root permissions, only killing the process may (but since there's no way to separate that from top...).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: So, the answer ended up being to restart Apache, did that and everything was fine. Again, thanks for all your replies, selecting you as the answer. +100... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or You may try htop :)

```
yum install htop
```

Comment: how would I use htop to solve this problem?

Comment: You can run htop command, then press F6 to sort by CPU, memory, etc usage, then select proccess from the list, then press F9 and select signal which will be send to the process, for example to send sigkill (9) press 9 and then hit enter :)

Answer (score 0):

Its unlikely to be delayed due to CPU usage - it should be spending most of its time sleeping while I/Os going on. And you should not kill the client process - kill the client connection on the DBMS - see

mysqladmin processlist

and

mysqladmin kill